# Find a sum of fractional series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{2n-1}}$$

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{n}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4}{3}$, but what should I use in my case?

Comment: This is a GP too but with a common ratio $\frac1{4^2}$. Also, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=\color{red}0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4^{n}} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4}{3}$

Comment: @SameerBaheti so its $\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-\frac{1}{16}}$ ?

Comment: Indeed! How to I pass the character limit of comment section lol

Comment: @SameerBaheti: I suggest you answer the question in the "answer" box and not in the "comment" box.

Comment: @SameerBaheti add `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$` in the end

Comment: @MartinArgerami Then why do some people suggest asking for a user's attempt first? ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: That only applies to when they first ask a question, not after someone gives a hint to the answer. Comments should be for discussing a question, and something that answers the question should be written as an answer.

Comment: @SameerBaheti: that has to do with the question, not with the answer. Some people want to see the asker's work as a way to fight "do my homework" questions. It has nothing to do with answering in the comment section. You answered in a comment, so the question still appeared as unanswered; and, meanwhile, someone answered the question and is getting the reputation you should have gotten.

Comment: @TobyMak Point! So, I should ask for the attempt first in the comment box and then provide the hint in the answer box.

Comment: Yes, you should always answer whenever you have the information to answer the question. I think that the OP knowing the sum of $\frac{1}{4^n}$ is already sufficient context, as it shows that they know how to use the geometric series formula, however, you might disagree.

Answer (score 4):

If in doubt, you can always write out the first few terms of the series:

$$S = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4^3} + \frac{1}{4^5} + \frac{1}{4^7} \cdots \tag{1}$$
$$\frac{1}{4^2}S = \frac{1}{4^3} + \frac{1}{4^5} + \frac{1}{4^7}\cdots \tag{2}$$

Since the series converges as $|r| < 1$, $(1) - (2)$ gives:

$$\frac{15}{16}S = \frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow S = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{16}{15} = \frac{4}{15}$$